# not abe to get rest-assured output value

Tags: java, json, api, postman, rest-assured

I am having an issue with rest-assured output. I am able to get result with Postman, also with java 11 Http API, I am getting a full response but not with RestAssured.

attaching screenshots

enter image description here[intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoki0.png)

enter image description here[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FssX4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I see is that you have 9 headers on Postman. Perhaps you are missing a header in RestAssured?

Comment: In postman i have 2 in headers which i am verifying my API and JSON type and getting 7 output headers.
the same i do in Intellij, i send 2 headers which is APIKey and Type Json and receiving the same 7 headers like in postman. But the value Empty.